# meaning of ギッタンギッタン with reference

Tags: definitions

I tried to add a definition for ギッタンギッタン to JDIC using references on the Internet.

http://www.edrdg.org/jmdictdb/cgi-bin/entr.py?e=1907714&svc=jmdict&sid=

They're slow to add it (or reject it) which is highly unusual. I'm guessing the provided references are not authoritative enough.

Would anybody have any good double checked references for this ?

the current definition I have is :

- (ギッタンギッタンにする、ギッタンギッタンにやる) to obliterate, to destroy completely, to inflict tremendous pain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any authoritative reference for now, but I think the definition you provided has room for improvement.

ギタギタ/ギッタギタ/ギタンギタン/etc is a mimetic word which describes the status of someone severely beat up by a fight. More common synonyms are "けちょんけちょん" and "こてんぱん". These can also be metaphorically used for one-sided arguments/debates/games. I have not seen ギタギタ used for inanimate objects (e.g. 車がギタギタになった).

And ギタギタ usually means to knock someone down, maybe until he loses consciousness, but does not imply complete destruction or death.

Comment: Thanks, the only reference I have is http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1390072123 , and it says ギッタンギッタン is a stronger form of ギタギタ implying thorough and complete . A search for ギッタンギッタン showed a complete victory in baseball, complete removal of acne. Also it seems to be used with other 擬態語, ボロボロのギッタンギッタン、ギッタンギッタンのケチョンケチョン, etc. Would 'ass-whooping' be a good translation or is it too vulgar ?

Comment: Additionally, the link gives a 日本国語大辞典 reference that I can't check, but probably available to JDIC editors (hopefully).

Comment: It's not really worth comparing the strength of ギッタンギッタン and ギタギタ -- they're basically the same. Using this for completely defeating an acne or a baseball team makes sense, but I think that's metaphorical. And sorry I don't know the feelings of "ass-whooping".

Comment: 'ass-whooping' is a metaphor for a win so complete it looks like punishment （お仕置き）, and it's slang. I was basically asking whether ギタギタ/... was vulgar, familiar or usable in daily conversation. I'm not even sure levels of politeness apply to 擬態語 since they convey emotion or shape of action.

Comment: There are slangy and rough-sounding words by nature. I don't expect them used in serious news articles. But it's generally safe to use these words in daily conversations, variety shows, and [cartoons for children](http://youtu.be/nV63utE8tcE?t=1m20s).