# Meaning of メロメロ, ギッタギタ and のす

Tags: meaning

EDIT : Part of the answer here :
[meaning of ギッタンギッタン with reference](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19833/meaning-of-%E3%82%AE%E3%83%83%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AE%E3%83%83%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3-with-reference)

---

The speaker just said :

> オレさまはおまえみたいなカスでもようしゃしねえぞ。
>
> I won't show mercy, even to a scum like you.

And continues with :

> メロメロのギッタギタにのしてやる。

I know めろめろ can mean "weeping uncontrollably", "to flare up" or "to collapse".

I suppose ぎったぎた is ぎたぎた and means "greasy, sticky".

And I guess のす means something like "To knock down someone" here.

But I just can't do the maths...

Comment: Looks like a similar line was originally said by the character ジャイアン from the manga ドラえもん.  The phrase should not be taken literally or analyzed seriously.  http://www5e.biglobe.ne.jp/~poh/jaianizm-2.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> オレさまはおまえみたいなカスでもようしゃしねえぞ。

I won't show mercy, even to a scum like you.

Yes, the translation seems to me O.K.

And regarding your next question,

> メロメロのギッタギタにのしてやる。

This is actually meaning nothing but full of slang.

Like in English, "I'm gonna beat a mother fucking scumbag like you right now" stuff.

However, interestingly, めろめろ has a definition in the dictionary.

http://gogen-allguide.com/me/meromero.html

Translation

> The word めろめろ has been used since Kamakura era and used in variety of ways.
>   According the dictionary about the origin of word, 名語記（めいごき）, it was used
>   to denote "stripping something thin" and from the dictionary in Edo era it was used
>   with the same meaning of "めそめそ”　（＝almost same with めろめろ). After Meiji era,
>   The word changed the meaning to denote "spreading fire". 
>   In modern times, "メロメロになる” is used towards the opposite sex, or a lovely child, 
>   due to a word めらめら that has the same meaning with めろめろ used in Meiji era ( 
>   flaring up = have crush on ). However, there is an another theory that holds that the 
>   word came from the English word "mellow", but since this word has been used from 
>   Kamakura era, so it is hard to think the theory is correct.

And about ギッタギタ, that is not defined in the above 語源辞典{ごげんじてん} (the dictionary of the origin of words), but I found in an English-Japanese the meaning.

http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/completely

completely = ぎったぎた。

However since according to 知恵袋{ちえぶくろ} (wisdom bag), as I said, it actually means
nothing but being used when taunting somebody or some kind of abusive word.

http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1010242465

Comment: So, supposing メロメロ is slang for let's say "collapsed" (大辞林 says : しまりなく崩れるさま。だらしがないさま。 and 大辞泉 says 自制力・抵抗力などを失うさま。) how are の and に used here?

Comment: Ahhhh.... my suggestion is, since language is not a math, even though each word has some origin going back to around AD 1000 or some and のす is certainly "knock down, beat, etc, etc", when combined, as is shown in 知恵袋, in total, that becomes nothing but ( almost ) a swearing word.......

Comment: So please take my explanation of each word just as an complimentary.

Comment: So even you can abbreviate some particle, when swear/taunt ing. For example "メタメタギッタギタにする。probably meaning "I'm gonna fucking end you here asshole". So thinking too deep into this I think won't bring anything more.